# How to decide on parameter of Executors.newFixedThreadPool

Tags: executors

What should be the appropriate value to assign to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)? Is there any formula of doing this?

Comment: Pretty much by definition, the maximum number of tasks that you want to be able to execute concurrently...

Comment: What is the difference between Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10) against Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20). What effect does it have on the application performance?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This would help

Comment: I've made my comments into an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the tasks you're going to be executing are mostly CPU bound (i.e. a task will be able to keep one CPU core going at 100% continuously) then you're unlikely to gain much from a thread pool larger than the number of cores on your machine. But if the tasks will be spending most of their time blocked for I/O then a larger pool will make better use of the available CPU capacity.

There's no simple answer, you have to profile your app with different pool sizes to find the sweet spot for the particular mix of tasks you're using.